# Did I merge my accounts or not?

Tags: support, reputation, user-accounts, merge-accounts, association-bonus

Today I managed to recover the password of my old account and wanted to merge it with my new one.
I changed the email address of the old account to the same one which is saved in my new account.

I didn't fill out the contact form yet [(like it is suggested here)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts).
But for some reason it did something to my accounts anyway.
I can now log in with both emails/passwords and end up in the same account.

Whats weird is this:
I got a 100 rep bonus from it. "you've earned a bonus of 100 reputation because we trust you on other sites in the network".
But I think it is also missing the reputation from one of the old accounts.
I've got 288 on Stack Overflow now. Both accounts had around 150. Plus 100 would equal to around 400. If I count all the reputation in my Stack Overflow profile manually I get to 387.

I'm kind of confused now.
Why did I get the 100 rep?
Did I keep my old points?
Do I still have to do something?

Comment: Ok, i've got 388 points now. Did a mod read this and fix it (thanks!) or was it just delayed?

Comment: Considering mods can’t do anything about this, no. It likely just took a bit to recalculate the reputation correctly.

Comment: It's possible that the system automatically merged the accounts.